# Which is more efficence when declaring Objective C objects

Tags: objective-c, oop, object

In title i used Objective C but this question is viable for other OOP Languages too, my question is this: **which of the declarations(samples) below is more efficent?**

1)

```
NSString        *urlString=@"string_literal_for_URL";
NSURL           *url         =   [NSURL urlWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest    *request     =   [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                              timeoutInterval:40];
NSURLConnection *connection  =   [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestFromLogin 
                                                                 delegate:self];
```

2)

```
NSURLRequest *requestFromLogin = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@/ipad/login.php?username=%@&password=%@",server.text,port.text,username.text,password.text]]  
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                              timeoutInterval:40];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestFromLogin delegate:self];
```

Note: As far as i remember from [CS193p Video Lectures](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10) iOS is good with lazy instantiation(as far as i understand, the first sample is better) but i'm not sure.. Can anyone please give an answer in OOP point of view.. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is just my opinion. I would go with example 1 most of the time, simply because its easier to read.  If you are trying to optimize the web service download, this issue will not improve performance by any measurable means.  Frankly youre over thinking it.  Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for questions like these.

Comment: This basically won't make ANY difference performancewise.

Comment: @scordova88 good comment, also it might be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight difference when the code is compiled with ARC and the optimization is turned off: the first example would increment and decrement a reference count on the `url` object one extra time. When optimization is turned on, however, the compiler should be able to figure out that the `url` variable is not used beyond the call to `NSURLRequest`'s initializer, and optimize it out.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally both examples are quite frankly the same. The only real difference here is that in the first example you can further re-use urlString, url, etc objects as you have access to their pointers.

Comment: but, for example won't one of them take much area from memory or some differences like that. I couldnt be sure yet

Comment: It's also easier to read and therefore easier to check it's right.

Comment: but wont it tire the cpu, or take too much of ram?(i mean the first one)

Comment: From the logical point of view there should be no difference, they are objects of the same type after all. Whether you still hold on to the pointer or just let it go immediately should not affect the memory consumption.